# What is a good sample project to get into Digital Twin

Tags: autodesk-forge, asset-management, azure-digital-twins, eclipse-digital-twin

we have developed a designed automation tool using Forge and VB.net to automate several tasks in the manufacturing/oil and gas industry, that makes the designing of pressure vessels take about a fourth of the time and steps required than without our tool. This is to say that we are familiar with the Forge and Inventor interfaces, but require your assistance in determining where to begin with for creating Digital Twins in the AEC industry and capitalize the platform for Asset Management.

I understand that Forge web service uses APIs such as - Data management, BIM 360, Model derivative and viewer, etc. We are looking to start with a sample project to get started in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [getting started tutorial](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/). And t[his sample](http://forge-digital-twin.autodesk.io/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-digital-twin))